# layerWithSession is unavailable in swift 2.0?

Tags: swift

Hello i have issue for AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

```
let previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.layerWithSession(captureSession) as AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    previewLayer.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    visageCameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
```

> 'layerWithSession' is unavailable: use object construction 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session:)'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message says, you must do

```
let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
```

Comment: I have the same code but previewLayer is nil and my app crashes... started happening in ios9